# Javascript: Wrong href in google maps marker list

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url, google-maps-markers, window.location

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am implementing the MarkerCluster function for google map markers. I am experiencing a problem, which seems very simple, but I have trouble to track it down.

The script gets a json string passed through a Django template. The displaying works fine, but the link of every marker is the same (last of the json list). **But the code seems straight forward to me that with every iteration a new href would be created. Isn't that correct?**

When I run the script all links redirect to the last item in the json list. How can I fix that?

```
var data = {{ project_data|safe }};
var markers = [];
for (var i = 1; i < {{ len|safe }}; i++) {
    var dat = data[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dat.lat, dat.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: dat.name,
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = "../projects/" + dat.link;  
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Thank you for your help & suggestions.

Comment: The reason is that all the click handlers access the *same* variable. Whose contents gets overwritten with every loop iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's variable scoping problem, just replace this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  window.location.href = "../projects/" + dat.link;  
});
```

with following

```
(function(dat) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = "../projects/" + dat.link;  
    });
})(dat);
```

Hope it'll solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes, it solves the problem! What is the syntax reason for encapsulating the addListener?

Comment: Welcome! In your example `var dat = data[i];` is in the global scope and that's why after the loop the last value assigned to all links. In my example I've used a closure. Read these to understand closure http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62 and http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures2.shtml.